# Impression tracking at scale

Tags: react-native, optimization, analytics, mixpanel

How to track impressions and watch time as product scale to millions of active users on the platform without hurting the app performance? we want to optimize the number of requests we need to make to analytics tool. We use mixpanel for analytics and have react native app.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you send your impressions asyncly to avoid hindering performance.

It's not the number of requests, it's the number of synced requests.

Second, you batch your tracking requests to avoid sending barely filled tcp-ip packets to the mixpanel endpoint. Not sure if mixpanel's sdk allows that natively. Firebase surely does.

Third, you limit the number of fields, number of events, length of strings just to fit more tracking events into the batched tcp packet.

Fourth, you consider changing the way you track impressions. There are a few different, not so straight approaches to tracking them. For example, if the products on the page are the same for every user who visits it, you don't need to send the same impressions for every user. You can just presume that every visit to this page automatically had all these impressions. You can even ETL your data from mixpanel to a more appropriate event storage and populate the table with supplemental impressions separately.

Finally, even if you don't do these optimizations and only make sure analytics is non-blocking, do you really see the difference in performance with and without analytics? Maybe the way you're generating your impression events payloads is harming the CPU somehow? Measure the exact point of what harms you. Analytics is an obvious thing to blame for the front-end, but it's rarely the real reason for performance issues.

Comment: Thank yo so much for your help!